# How to set "unchained transaction mode" from entity manager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to call a stored procedure using native query call from an entity manager like this

```
String command = "..."//my stored procedure call command
Query q =  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(command);
```

But when i run it I got the following message:

> Exception, procedure ... can be run
>   only in unchained transaction mode...

I know if I have a connection object, i can set con.setAutoComit(true) to make this work.
But my question is: since I have a entity manager object, can i set this somehow from entity manager object? I'd like to have the container to manage all the database resources...

I am using EclipseLink.

thanks.

One more note: i don't have the control over the database side,so i cannot go and change the transaction mode to "any".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("set chained off").executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

What database/JDBC driver are you using?
Are you using Sybase JConnect?  I think it had this issue with some stored procedure calls.

If you cannot fix the issue on the database/drvier, EclipseLink has an option for this.

Using a SessionCustomizer you can set,

```
session.getLogin().handleTransactionsManuallyForSybaseJConnect();
```

This will only work if EclipseLink has control of the transactions, not with JTA.